# Get only the Id for the target td element in a table

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get only the id of a td element in a table with an inputClickHandler?
because if I do for example e.currentTarget or e.target it stores this in it: `<td id='square0'>5</td>`. I want it to store only the id. For the example above I want to store only `square0`.
Thank you, your answer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.target.id`. id is a property of DOM element.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td id="1">Row 1</td></tr>
<tr><td id="2">Row 2</td></tr>
<tr><td id="3">Row 3</td></tr>
<tr><td id="4">Row 4</td></tr>
<tr><td id="5">Row 5</td></tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", "td", function(e) {
                var data = $(this).attr('id');
                alert (data);
            }); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you use jquery it will be easier. I have made a simple page to demonstrate example of jquery code.

Comment: I just started working with javascript and i'm looking for a way to get the index position of the td that was clicked. How can i do that?